# Weird SSH, Server security, I might have been hacked

Tags: linux, ssh, security, hacking

I am not sure if I've been hacked or not.

I tried to log in through SSH and it wouldn't accept my password. Root login is disabled so I went to rescue and turned root login on and was able to log in as root. As root, I tried to change the password of the affected account with the same password with which I had tried to log in before, `passwd` replied with "password unchanged". I then changed the password to something else and was able to log in, then changed the password back to the original password and I was again able to log in.

I checked `auth.log` for password changes but didn't find anything useful.

I also scanned for viruses and rootkits and the server returned this:

ClamAV:

```
"/bin/busybox Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5607459-1 FOUND"
```

RKHunter:

```
"/usr/bin/lwp-request Warning: The command '/usr/bin/lwp-request' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/lwp-request: a /usr/bin/perl -w script, ASCII text executable

Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:"
```

It should be noted that my server isn't widely known. I have also changed the SSH port and enabled 2-step verification.

I am worred I got hacked and someone is trying to fool me, "everything is fine don't worry about it".

Comment: Agree with Michael. Seems like Mirai uses brute-force password guessing to compromise linux hosts - https://www.incapsula.com/blog/malware-analysis-mirai-ddos-botnet.html. Using public key authentication would be better than changing the SSH port for security purposes IMHO.

Comment: You might have your var log partition full, and you cant change the root password when in rescue because first you have to mount the partitions properly as read-write

Comment: @JoshMorel I would go further and say that changing the SSH port is _detrimental_ to security. It doesn't help protect anything, but people who do it wrongly _feel_ more secure. So, by feeling more secure without actually being more secure they're worse off than before. Also, I'd say pubkey auth isn't simply better, but a must.

Comment: _"... it wouldn't accept my password ... it replied "password unchanged" ... after changing the password to something else I was able to login, I changed the password back to what it was and I was still able to login."_ - All that _could_ be explained by you making typos in your password (or having caps lock on) before you went to the rescue user.

Comment: the busybox trojan detection by clamav happened to me, too, this morning for the first time ever, across ~100 systems; I'm voting false positive. I'd guess clamav updated their sig database to have this false positive start showing up overnight last night

Comment: Incidentally, the sha256 hashsum of my busybox on these systems is 7fa3a176871de12832ca8a78b646bc6be92f7f528ee81d1c35bf12aa99292b1c  . These are ubuntu 14.04 systems, and the mtime on the busybox bin is 2013-11-14

Comment: Have you read through `/usr/bin/lwp-request`?  Does it look suspicious?

Comment: @marcelm, if you're paying attention to your logs, it's helpful: it gets rid of all the automated scanners, so you *know* that any log entries are from a serious attacker.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Like J Rock, I think this is a false positive.  I had the same experience.

I received an alarm from 6 different, disparate, geographically separated servers in a short time span.  4 of these servers only existed on a private network.  The one thing they had in common was a recent daily.cld update.

So, after checking for some of the typical heuristics of this trojan without success, I booted a vagrant box with my known clean baseline and ran freshclam.  This grabbed

> "daily.cld is up to date (version: 22950, sigs: 1465879, f-level: 63,
>   builder: neo)"

A subsequent `clamav /bin/busybox` returned the same "/bin/busybox Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5607459-1 FOUND" alert on the original servers.

Finally, for good measure, I also did a vagrant box from Ubuntu's official [box](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64) and also got the same "/bin/busybox Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5607459-1 FOUND"  (Note, I had to up the memory on this vagrant box from its default 512MB or clamscan failed with 'killed')

Full output from fresh Ubuntu 14.04.5 vagrant box.

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# freshclam
ClamAV update process started at Fri Jan 27 03:28:30 2017
main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790, f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer)
daily.cvd is up to date (version: 22950, sigs: 1465879, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
bytecode.cvd is up to date (version: 290, sigs: 55, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# clamscan /bin/busybox
/bin/busybox: Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5607459-1 FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 5679215
Engine version: 0.99.2
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 1
Infected files: 1
Data scanned: 1.84 MB
Data read: 1.83 MB (ratio 1.01:1)
Time: 7.556 sec (0 m 7 s)
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~#
```

So, I also believe this is likely to be a false positive.

I will say, rkhunter did *not* give me the: "/usr/bin/lwp-request Warning" reference, so maybe PhysiOS Quantum is having more than one issue.

EDIT: just noticed that I never explicitly said that all of these servers are Ubuntu 14.04.  Other versions may vary?

Comment: I am going to change my SSH authentication for a pubkey and I will try to monitor the network connections, but honestly it's really wierd because I even copy and pasted the password and it still rejected it. What should I do with the /usr/bin/lwp-request?

Comment: I also got this notification this morning on a Ubuntu 14.04 server. I compared (`sha1sum`) my server's `/bin/busybox` file to the same file on a local VM created from an Ubuntu image and they're identical. So I vote false positive too.

Comment: @PhysiOSQuantum Nothing. That's also a false positive -- lwp-request is a tool related to a Perl module (https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP), so it's perfectly normal for it to be a script.

Answer (score 44):

The ClamAV signature for Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5607459-1 is definitely too broad, so it's likely a false positive, as noted by J Rock and cayleaf.

For example, any file that has all of the following properties will match the signature:

- it's an ELF file;
- it contains the string "watchdog" exactly twice;
- it contains the string "/proc/self" at least once;
- it contains the string "busybox" at least once.

(The whole signature is a bit more complicated, but the above conditions are sufficient for a match.)

For example, you can create such a file with:

```
$ echo 'main() {printf("watchdog watchdog /proc/self busybox");}' > innocent.c
$ gcc -o innocent innocent.c
$ clamscan --no-summary innocent
innocent: Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5607459-1 FOUND
```

Any busybox build (on Linux) will usually match the four properties I listed above. It's obviously an ELF file and it will definitely contain the string "busybox" many times. It [executes "/proc/self/exe"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274322) to run certain applets. Finally, "watchdog" occurs twice: once as an applet name and once inside the string "/var/run/watchdog.pid".

Comment: Where can I read that signature, and others from ClamAV, out of curiosity?

Comment: I knew someone smarter than me would be able to explain *why* it was a false positive. Thanks!

Comment: @Délisson Junio: Create an empty directory, cd into it and run `sigtool --unpack-current daily` to unpack daily.cvd (or `sigtool --unpack-current main` to unpack main.cvd). If you grep the resulting files for "Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5607459-1", you should find the signature, which happens to be in daily.ldb. The signature format is explained in [signatures.pdf](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-devel/blob/master/docs/signatures.pdf) (comes with the clamav-docs package in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 6):

This just showed up today for me as well in my ClamAV scan for /bin/busybox.  I'm wondering if the updated database has an error.

Comment: Scan /bin/busybox on any Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the latest ClamAV database.  It returns infected.  This is a false positive, IMO.

Comment: I submitted a false positive report to ClamAV.  

I also found that vmware player binaries show up as infected with the same trojan.  It's likely they have included busybox code.

Answer (score 4):

> I tried to log in through SSH and it wouldn't accept my password. Root login is disabled so I went to rescue and turned root login on and was able to log in as root. As root, I tried to change the password of the affected account with the same password with which I had tried to log in before, passwd replied with "password unchanged". I then changed the password to something else and was able to log in, then changed the password back to the original password and I was again able to log in.

This sounds like expired password.  Setting the password (successfully) by root resets the password expiration clock.  You *could* check /var/log/secure (or whatever is the Ubuntu equivalent) and find out why your password was rejected.